# How create stateful service in @RabbitListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

How can create the stateful service (several @Autowire) in the message (@RabbitListener) and if new message, state should be clean. 
Before the RabbitQM(Spring AMQP) for @Service I used `@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` but now it does not work.

Comment: Please create a MVC example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The `SCOPE_REQUEST` doesn't work with the `@RabbitListener` because it is not a Web at all. You are good with the `SCOPE_REQUEST/SESSION` in the MVC application because your service is called from the servlet container with an appropriate environment and really scope.

When you do your logic in the `@RabbitListener` you should keep in mind that this one reacts to the message polled from the RabbitMQ queue by the listener container and that last one does it in the infinite loop spinned by the `Executor` in the particular thread. The scope is not going to work here.

What you may consider to do to deal with the state is something like `ThreadLocal` filled in your `@RabbitListener` and accessed from the call stack down the service road. That is exactly how Spring `SecurityContext` is managed.